# Is Apache caching request URLs?

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm sitting here trying to find a way around URL-rewriting for my new site. It's going to be a fully AJAX-based site where the URL has no importance in 90 % of the URL's.

After pressing F12 in Chrome and going to Network, I started monitoring the responsiveness as I changed the parameters in .htaccess.

I found that when entering an address that the server hadn't seen since restart, it spent 80-100ms to process the request (wait time). This is running on the localhost. This occured both when changing the dynamic part of the GET-request ?id=changeThis and when entering new URLs like /id/changeThis.. The next time however, it takes 8-12ms to process...

If I use `^(.*)` to redirect all requests to index.php didn't have an impact.

Question: Would it in a bigger scale matter if I use `^([a-zA-Z\-/]*)` (notice no period) to make static files like main.css not be rewritten, or is it best to put all files in a static folder (and thus loose flexibility) and still use `^(.*)` to redirect all requests not in the static exception folder. (I'm thinking speed here.)

Question: Can anyone approve my findings? Does Apache really 'cache' the requests, so that the first request to a specific URL will take time to process?

Comment: Apache itself doesn't do any "caching". However, depending on which programming language or framework you're using, an additional amount of time may be required for the first hit to a URL to load the actual code that runs.

Comment: @GregHewgill Actually I was requesting files that did not exist. So PHP never actually loaded..

Comment: possible places files are cached: browser, firewall, router, isp, any sever between host and user.

Comment: @Dagon Ok, so it cannot be the browser (I cleared the cache), it cannot be the router (it's localhost), therefore not the isp either, let's try flushdns.

Comment: @Dagon No, can't be any of those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

Processing will be faster with less clauses, and a simpler regex - but we are talking on the order of a couple ms.

Apache does not cache requests in the way you are thinking - however, your linux system may be caching files, so subsequent loads are faster.  I would think this is what you are seeing/thinking - both apache and website files are cached in the OS in pages for faster access.  A restart should make these pages dirty and need a reload of them.

Answer (score 1):

Disable mod_cache from the Apache configuration.
 In my configuration it was enabled by default.

Comment: It's not on by default here.

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts what problems? I think you were trying to find out if apache caches responses?

Comment: I found mod_cache affected the response in two times - one it was not picking changes to the file (eg, if I uploaded an updated page it was not picked) and adding headers which enabled client side caching - which was something I did NOT want (being my site fully dynamic). Of course the web server uses the url to address the cache, identical URLs will hit the cache on the second request, if you alter the url even slightly (different page but also different/additional parameters) the server has no way to tell the page would not be different and has to return the "true", uncached version

Comment: Do you think it is on, even though it is not to be found in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: In my system, in addition to the httpd.conf file, I have httpd.d folders with various settings. There are way to dump a list of all the loaded modules - but the way you do it is system dependant